# How to Customize ANTLR exception in C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, antlr3

I am using ANTLR 3

I am trying to custom the exception message raised from Praser.

Expression which I am using :-

```
2+*3
```

Error message recived from ANTLR is :

```
no viable alternative at input '*' line 1:3
```

I want to custom this exception message to

```
 Invalid Expression Term line 1:3
```

I tried to override `GetErrorMessage(RecognitionException e, string[] tokenNames)` method of parser but not able to figure out how to customize this description.
Similar to these I've to customize other exception message also.

Can anyone provide me some initial guidance how to proceed with this issue.

I am using c# 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model your implementation of `GetErrorMessage` after the one in `BaseRecognizer`. All of the message templates are included in this method.

https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/blob/master/runtime/CSharp3/Sources/Antlr3.Runtime/BaseRecognizer.cs#L275

Comment: 404 not found. :-( This is why it's always better to copy the answer than to link on SO...

Comment: What would be a ANTLR4 solution?

Answer (score 1):

Catch the `NoViableAltException` and any other `RecognitionException` derived exceptions and throw out your own exception. The line number and column number can be picked up from `RecognitionException.Line` and `RecognitionException.CharPositionInLine`.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented in this way probably it may benifit others also :-

In my parser class :-

```
public override string GetErrorMessage(RecognitionException e, string[] tokenNames)
    {
            String msg = string.Empty;
            if (e is NoViableAltException)
            {
                msg = "Invalid Expression Term";
            }
            else if (e is UnwantedTokenException)
            {
                msg = "Bracket Mismatch";
            }
            else if (e is MissingTokenException)
            {
                msg = "Invalid Parameter";
            }
            else
            {
                base.GetErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);
            }
            return msg;
    }
```